# Is there a way to turn an alternating series/sum into a strictly positive one?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's say I have an alternating sum
$$S = \sum_i (-1)^i a_i,$$
where the coefficients $a_i$ are all positive rational numbers, and we assume $S > 0$. What methods are available to obtain a derived sum/series
$$\sum_k b_k = S,$$
where the $b_k$ are all positive rational numbers. While I am particularly interested in the case $k=i$, solutions and methods with $k \neq i$ are also appreciated.

I'm thinking along the lines of a [Moebius-type] inversion, or [Chu–Vandermonde-type] identity.

Here's a concrete example. For positive integers $a$ and $n$, define the *sum of integer powers* function
$$S_n(a) = 1^n + 2^n + \dotsb + a^n.$$
An easily-derived relation is
$$S_n(a) = \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r \binom{n}{r} S_{n-r}(a+1).  \tag{$\star$}$$
There are, of course, other [all-positive] relations. But can one explicitly turn ($\star$) into
$$S_n(a) = \sum_{r=0}^n a_r S_{n-r}(a+1)$$
[or similar] with all $a_r > 0$?

Comment: Sometimes one can use grouping.

Comment: Consider all partial sums and select a subsequence that goes increasing. Then subtract these sums pairwise. As in general $k<i$, you have freedom to split the $b_k$'s to keep synchronized with the original series.

Answer (score 2):

If
$|a_n| > |a_{n+1}|$
then
$\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1} (-1)^i a_i
=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a_{2i}-a_{2i+1})
$.
If
$a_{2i} > a_{2i+1}$,
then you have a 
sum of positive terms.

Comment: I believe that's what @AndréNicolas was getting at with his "grouping" comment/suggestion. I'm hoping for an answer which is less elementary, e.g., one by which one could obtain a sum with an equal number of summands ($k=i$).

Comment: For me, this is the most common thing done, so I decided to make it explicit.

Comment: True. I upvoted accordingly.